How to mock variables in a template in a Jest unit test for an Angular application?
I meet a problem in a jest unit test.
the code for the html looks jest like this:
<ng-container *ngVar="personFacade.personInfo$ | async as personInfo">
 @if (personInfo.active){
  <childcomponent1></childcomponent1>
 }@else 
{ <childcomponent2></childcomponent2>
}
</ng-container>

the logic is simple.
in my jest test, I have mock this personfacde and return a mock value for personInfo.
  function mockPersonInfo(): jest.Mock<any, any> {
    return MockInstance(PersonFacade, 'personInfo$', jest.fn(), 'get').mockReturnValue(of(personInfo));
  }

and in the test I want to check if personInfo active = false
should only childcomponent2 will be shown.
and my test looks like this:

it('should show only childcomponent2', () => {
 mockPersonInfo();
 component = fixture.point.componentInstance;
 fixture.detectChanges();

  const childcomponent1 = ngMocks.find('childcomponent1');
  expect(childcomponent1).toBeFalsy();
});


but  I got error message:
Cannot find an element via ngMocks.find('childcomponent1')
If I move e.g childcomponent1 out of the ng-container,
the test can find this component1.
so I assume that there is some problem with mocking data in ng-container.

Could you share the implementation of the "ngVar" directive as well? It's not a standard Angular directive. Also, could you provide the TestBed to understand how you initialize your test?

Could you try changing it to, we are mocking the facade after the component is initialized, which might be the problem is my understanding.
function mockPersonInfo(component): jest.Mock<any, any> {
    return MockInstance(component.personFacade, 'personInfo$', jest.fn(), 'get').mockReturnValue(of(personInfo));
}

Then call it like
it('should show only childcomponent2', () => {
 mockPersonInfo(component);
 component = fixture.point.componentInstance;
 fixture.detectChanges();

  const childcomponent1 = ngMocks.find('childcomponent1');
  expect(childcomponent1).toBeFalsy();
});

